# Parse string as DateTime in Javascript from JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, datetime

I want send a datetime in JSON with string fromat from asp.net web service  and I want javascript parse it like datetime and not like string.

So I ask is there a special format that I must use it to  convert datetime to string and parse it in javascript as datetime?

In fact , I don't want touch javascript. I want javascript read the string and considerate it as DateTime.

Comment: Just to add: this could help you http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/

Comment: If you want to get into details, you might want to read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your date strings conform [rfc2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and use javascript [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method.

Alternatively, send your dates over as integer milliseconds and use [Date constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the javascript side.

Answer (score 0):

I used [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) for a few projects using ASP.NET. The format will probably depend on your locale. I would looks at the data.js examples to make it work the way it would fit your specification and locale.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code I use to create a date from a .net JSON serialized DateTime object.

```
function formatJSONDate(jsonDate) {
    var d = new Date((jsonDate.slice(6, -2)*1));

    var day = d.getDate() * 1;
    var month = (d.getMonth() * 1) +1;

    var s = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day + "-" + (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month + "-" + d.getFullYear();

    return s;
}
```